# Elasticsearch - ignore property from being persisted

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have beans that I am persisting to database and I also want to persist them to elasticsearch. But there I have a problem, for example, in country bean there is collection of cities, and every city has country filed. When I try to save it to elasticsearch I get exception:
**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion**

Is there a way to mark filed not to be persisted to elasticsearch, I tried to  use @Transient but it doesn't help me.

@JsonInclude is not an option, because I also use this beans to return information to client through REST.

```
    @Document(indexName = "cities", type = "city", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1", indexStoreType = "memory")
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CITY")
    @SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE CITY SET deleted = 1 WHERE City_id = ? AND version=?")
    @Where(clause = "deleted = 0")
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "$resolved", "$promise", "deleted" })
    public class CityEntity implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5696224598424579197L;

        @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "City_id")
        protected Long id;

        @Version
        protected int version;

        @Field(type = FieldType.Boolean, store = false)
        protected boolean deleted;

        @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
        @Column(name = "code")
        protected String code;

        @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
        protected String name;

        @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, store = false)
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "country")
        protected CountryEntity country;

        @JsonProperty("id")
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(final Long newId) {
            id = newId;
        }

        @JsonProperty("deleted")
        public Boolean getDeleted() {
            return deleted;
        }

        public void setDeleted(final Boolean newDeleted) {
            deleted = newDeleted;
        }

        @JsonProperty("version")
        public int getVersion() {
            return version;
        }

        public void setVersion(final int newVersion) {
            version = newVersion;
        }

        @JsonProperty("code")
        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(final String newcode) {
            code = newcode;
        }

        @JsonProperty("name")
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(final String newname) {
            name = newname;
        }

        @JsonProperty("country")
        public CountryEntity getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(final CountryEntity newcountry) {
            country = newcountry;
        }

        }

@Document(indexName = "countries", type = "country", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1", indexStoreType = "memory")
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE COUNTRY SET deleted = 1 WHERE Country_id = ? AND version=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted = 0")
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler","$resolved","$promise", "deleted" })
public class CountryEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1804208351747583363L;

@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Country_id")
    protected Long id;

    @Version
    protected int version;

    protected boolean deleted;

@Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
    protected String code;

@Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    protected String name;

@Field(type = FieldType.Nested, store = false)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @Where(clause = "deleted = 0")
    protected Set<CityEntity> cities = new HashSet<CityEntity>();

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long newId) {
        id = newId;
    }
    @JsonProperty("deleted")
    public Boolean getDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }
    public void setDeleted(Boolean newDeleted) {
        deleted = newDeleted;
    }
    @JsonProperty("version")
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(int newVersion) {
        version = newVersion;
    }
    @JsonProperty("code")
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String newcode) {
        code = newcode;
    }
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String newname) {
        name = newname;
    }

    @JsonProperty("cities")
    public Set<CityEntity> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCities(Set<CityEntity> newcities) {
        cities = newcities;
    }
    }
```

Comment: which field do you want to ignore? why don't you add it to `@JsonIgnoreProperties`?

Comment: I would like to ignore cities field in CountryEntity. Well, then I would not be able to return it through REST to client application.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. You want to use the same bean and the same mapper, but ignore some fields depending on the endpoint? sorry, cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to customize what to include to json with JsonView as said there: [Ignore JsonIgnore in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765996/ignore-jsonignore-in-elasticsearch)

You may create two views, one for Rest, another for Elasticsearch and mark the field with the needed one. And tell to Elasticsearch's ObjectMapper to work with specific JsonView only