# Ignore JsonIgnore in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, jackson

I am developing an application which uses Spring-boot, a relational database and Elasticsearch.

I use JSON serialization at 2 differents places in the code:

- In the response of the REST API.
- When the code interacts with Elasticsearch.

There are some properties that I need in Elasticsearch but that I want to hide to the application user (e.g. internal ids coming from the relational database).

Here is an example of entity :

```
@Document
public class MyElasticsearchEntity {

  @Id
  private Long id; //I want to hide this to the user.
  private String name;
  private String description;
}
```

**Problem** : When the object it persisted in Elasticsearch, it gets serialized as JSON. Hence, fields with `@JsonIgnore` are ignored when serialized to Elasticsearch.

Up to now, I found 2 unsatisfying solutions :

**Solution 1** : Use `@JsonProperty` like this :

```
@Id
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
private Long id;
```

The `id` gets written in Elasticsearch and is nullified in the JSON response :

```
{
  "id" : null,
  "name" : "abc",
  "description" : null
}
```

So it works but the application user still sees that this property exists. This is messy.

**Solution 2** : Cutomize the object mapper to ignore null values

Spring-boot has a built-in option for that :

```
spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=NON_NULL
```

Problem : it suppresses all non-null properties, not only those that I want to ignore. Suppose that the field `description` of the previous entity is empty, the JSON response will be :

```
{
  "name" : "abc"
}
```

And this is problematic for the UI.

So is there a way to ignore such field only in the JSON response?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [Jackson JsonView](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) for your purpose. You can define one view which will be used to serialize pojo for the application user :

Create the views as class, one public and one private:

```
class Views {
         static class Public { }
         static class Private extends Public { }
}
```

Then uses the view in your Pojo as an annotation:

```
@Id
@JsonView(Views.Private.class) String name;
private Long id;
@JsonView(Views.Public.class) String name;
private String publicField;
```

and then serialize your pojo for the application user using the view:

```
objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, beanInstance, Views.Public.class);
```

This is one example of many others on how view can fit your question. Eg. you can use too `objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);` to exclude field without view annotation and remove the `Private` view.